# Android Webview data not displaying

Tags: php, android, json, webview

I am trying parse some data to a form in php.But the below is happening.
Is there any error in this code because this prints the php echo of a webview in log cat but the values are not being displayed in webview.

```
 x=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
            tot=getIntent().getStringExtra("total");
            fuel=getIntent().getStringExtra("fuel");
            phone=getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
            mail=getIntent().getStringExtra("driver_email");

            Log.e("name", x);

            try {
                postData();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
        public void postData() throws JSONException{
             StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
                        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
                            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(payUrl);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                // JSON data:
                json.put("name", x);
                json.put("total", tot);
                json.put("fuel", fuel);
                json.put("phone", phone);
                json.put("mail", mail);


                JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
                postjson.put(json);

                // Post the data:
                httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
                httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                System.out.print(json);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // for JSON:
                if(response != null)
                {
                    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    y = sb.toString();
                    Log.e("y",y);
                }
```

The php code receiving the data is

```
 $data = json_decode($json);
    echo "Array: \n";
    echo "--------------\n";
    var_dump($data,true);
    echo "\n\n";

    $name= $data->name;
     $mail= $data->mail;
      $phone= $data->phone;
       $fuel= $data->fuel;
        $total= $data->total;
    $pos = $data->position;

    echo $data->name;
    echo "Result: \n";
    echo "--------------\n";
    echo "Name     : ".$name."\n Position : ".$pos."\n mail: ".$mail."\n phone : ".$phone."\n fuel : ".$pos."\ total : ".$pos;
```

But when I am trying to echo values are not popping.Any help
 i am adding my logcat and echo for better underxsxtanding

```
 JSON: -------------- NULL Array: -------------- NULL Result: -------------- Name : Position : mail: phone : fuel : \ total :

Log Cat:

06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): JSON: 
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): --------------
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): string(80) "{"name":"s","total":"82.73","fuel":"Petrol","phone":"22","mail":"abc@gmail.com"}"
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): Array: 
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): --------------
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   ["name"]=>
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   string(1) "s"
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   ["total"]=>
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   string(5) "82.73"
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   ["fuel"]=>
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   string(6) "Petrol"
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   ["phone"]=>
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   string(2) "22"
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   ["mail"]=>
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):   string(13) "abc@gmail.com"
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): }
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): sResult: 
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): --------------
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205): Name     : s
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):  Position : 
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):  mail: abc@gmail.com
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):  phone : 22
06-08 10:22:30.017: E/y(13205):  fuel : \ total : fff
```

Comment: are you sure you are sending content-type in php codes?

Comment: NO i am not sure,and i am not that fluent with PHP.Can you help me.

Comment: insert `header("Content-Type: text/html");` before your echo's

Comment: No even it did nopt work i am adding my php and logcat also for better understanding